# Bug on filter with java

Tags: bug, tags, search

I was visiting a questions & had filters by java but i found that there is a question that was not related to java.

I don't know how this happens?

It is about HTML & css:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Caching. Always blame caching. That particular question [was originally tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20047364/revisions) [java](/questions/tagged/java), so you just caught it before it dropped off of the list after being edited to remove the incorrect tags.